# Convert string fraction into float

Tags: postgresql

We're trying to convert in PostgreSQL something like this:

```
select '1/2'::float;

ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type double precision: "1/2"
LINE 1: select '1/2'::float;
```

And actually this works:

```
select 1/2::float;
  ?column? 
----------
    0.5
```

Are we missing something? We have tried `to_number`... The only solution we came threw was to use `split`...

Comment: select 1/2::float as columnname    or      select replace('1/2','/','.')::float as columnname

Comment: @areklipno 1/2 is not the same as 1.2 ...

Comment: sorry - my mistake....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are we missing something?

Yes, you are.

`1/2::float` means "the value 1 divided by the value 2 cast as a float".

`'1/2'::float` means: cast the string `'1/2'` to a float value - but the `/` character is invalid for a number constant.

A valid number in SQL consists of the digit 0-9 a dot `.` for the decimal separator and optionally an `e` to indicate exponential values (e.g. 1e6 for "one million"). So `'1/2'::float` is wrong in the same way as `'1(2'::float` or `'1 divided by 2'::float`

---

And before you ask for a function to do that for you, see the following questions for a generic "eval()" function:

- [Eval Calculation-string: "2 * 3 + 4 * 5" in Postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43118512/eval-calculation-string-2-3-4-5-in-postgresql)
- [Are there any way to execute a query inside the string value (like eval) in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433201/are-there-any-way-to-execute-a-query-inside-the-string-value-like-eval-in-post)
- [How to evaluate expression in select statement in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26063328/how-to-evaluate-expression-in-select-statement-in-postgres)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

(Borrowing from https://xzilla.net/blog/2006/Dec/sql-servers-charindex-function-in-postgresql.html and Ross Pressor's answer at [Convert fractional string to decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27051412/convert-fractional-string-to-decimal) for SQL Server)

```
create or replace function charindex(text, text, integer) returns integer as $$
begin
    return 
        case 
        when strpos(substr($2, $3 + 1), $1) = 0 
        then 0
        else strpos(substr($2, $3+1), $1) + $3 
        end;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

create or replace function fraction_to_decimal ( frac varchar(100) ) returns decimal as $$
begin
    return case 
        when frac like '% %/%'
            then cast(left(frac, charindex(' ', frac, 1) -1) as decimal) + 
                ( cast(substring(frac, charindex(' ', frac, 1) + 1, charindex('/', frac, 1)-charindex(' ',frac,1)-1) as decimal) 
                / cast(right(frac, length(frac) - charindex('/', frac, 1)) as decimal) )
        when frac like '%/%'
            then cast(left(frac, charindex('/', frac, 1) - 1) as decimal) / cast(right(frac, length(frac) - charindex('/', frac, 1)) as decimal)
        else 
            cast(frac as decimal) 
        end;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Then: `SELECT fraction_to_decimal('1/2');`

Also works fine for nulls: `SELECT fraction_to_decimal(null)`;